# How to get the data source information from a SSRS report, using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, reporting-services

I am currently making an ASP.Net and C# page, which is a front end for some reports.

I also want to run some queries, from the same data source as the reports (each report uses just 1 data source).

Is it possible to extract the data source connection information from a report, using either ReportingService2005 or ReportExecutionService members, so that it can be reused in an SqlConnection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ReportingService2005 API to get the datasource used by a particular report.

You need the full path of the report (which I assume you have), and then use it to query the reporting service for its data source ([API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.wssux.reportingserviceswebservice.rsmanagementservice2005.reportingservice2005.getitemdatasources(SQL.90).aspx)).

```
// rs = ReportingService2005 that you need to set up.

DataSource ds;
DataSources dataSources = rs.GetItemDataSources(item);

// item is a string containing the full path to the report.

dataSources = rs.GetItemDataSources(item);
ds = dataSources[0];
```

The ds in the code above is either a [DataSourceDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.wssux.reportingserviceswebservice.rsmanagementservice2005.datasourcedefinition.connectstring(SQL.90).aspx) or a 
[DataSourceReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.wssux.reportingserviceswebservice.rsmanagementservice2005.datasourcereference(SQL.90).aspx). If it's a definition you can just cast it into that type and then get the connection string using the following code.

```
DataSourceDefinition dsd = ds as DataSourceDefinition();
if(dsd == null)
    throw new Exception();

String connectionString = dsd.ConnectString;
```

If it's a datasourcereference you need to check out the [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159728(SQL.90).aspx).

Comment: VB's a bit rusty? The OP specified C# as the language they are using

Comment: The VB code was enough for me to get it working in C#, it does exactly what I want - Thank you :)

Comment: @csjohnst: Now that you mention it.. :) The script I was doing this in was in VB so I got confused..

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is of some help. It will list all the properties, but specifically it pulls out the connection string:

```
using System;
using GetPropertiesSample.ReportService2010; //This is the WebService Proxy
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.IO;

namespace GetPropertiesSample
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Get_Properties_of_DataSource_given_The_Path_and_Name_of_the_Report();
    }

    private static void Get_Properties_of_DataSource_given_The_Path_and_Name_of_the_Report()
    {
        try
        {

            // Create a Web service proxy object and set credentials
            ReportingService2010 rs = new ReportingService2010();
            rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            string reportPathAndName = "/0_Contacts/209_Employee_Telephone_List_Printable";

            DataSource[] dataSources = rs.GetItemDataSources(reportPathAndName);

            DataSource ds = dataSources[0];
            string dsName = ds.Name;
            Debug.Print("----------------------------------------------------");
            Debug.Print("Data Source Name: " + dsName);
            Debug.Print("----------------------------------------------------");
            DataSourceDefinition dsd = (DataSourceDefinition)ds.Item;
            if (dsd != null)
            {
                //Here is one property
                string connectionString = dsd.ConnectString;  // <======   HERE is the Connection Strin
                //Use Reflection to get all the properties :    using System.Reflection;
                var typeDSD = typeof(DataSourceDefinition);
                var properties = typeDSD.GetProperties();
                foreach (PropertyInfo p in properties)
                {
                    Debug.Print("----------------------------------------------------");
                    Debug.Print(p.Name + ": " + p.GetValue(dsd, null));
                }
            }

        }
        catch (SoapException e)
        {
            Debug.Print("==============================");
            Debug.Print(e.Detail.OuterXml);
            Debug.Print("==============================");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Print("==============================");
            Debug.Print(e.Message);
            Debug.Print(e.InnerException.ToString());
            Debug.Print(e.ToString());
            Debug.Print("==============================");
        }
    }
 }
```