# Show connection string in the report?

Tags: reporting-services

DataSource object does not contain such property because it is the base class for various kinds of datasources. Nonetheless this DataSource is of SQL Server type so the notion of ConnectionString is valid.

Is there any way to extract this information from the DataSource?

Answer (score 1):

Okay first off, why?  Doing such things as exposing connection strings exposes security risks and is a bad practice to even get involved in.  Saying that there are few things but none of them are that elegant and more involved.

1. If your report is 'deployed' there is a catalog on 'ReportServer' on the server that SSRS is installed under.  This assumes you have an SSRS server and the report is a 'hosted' RDL report NOT an RDLC report.  Saying that the sql you could put in a dataset to get these would be similar to:

   ```
   WITH  ItemContentBinaries AS 
   (
   SELECT
       Name
   ,   Type
   ,   CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), Content) AS Content
   FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog
   WHERE Type = 5 -- datasources
   )
   , ItemContentNoBOM AS 
   (
   SELECT
       Name
   ,   CASE WHEN LEFT(Content, 3) = 0xEFBBBF THEN CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),     SUBSTRING(Content, 4,LEN(Content)))
           ELSE Content 
           END AS Content
   FROM ItemContentBinaries
   )
   , xmlcontent as 
   (
   SELECT
       Name AS DataSourceName
   ,   CONVERT(xml, replace(Content, 'xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2006/03/reportdatasource"', '') ) AS ContentXML
   FROM ItemContentNoBOM 
   )
   Select     
   DataSourceName
   ,   ContentXML
   ,   ContentXML.query('/DataSourceDefinition/ConnectString/.').value('.', 'varchar(max)')
   from xmlcontent
   ```
2. You may attempt to place 'Custom Code' in your report and get the connection string from the rdl language.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/27de3f46-5174-480d-b4d1-5e32772dae35/ssrs-2005-custom-code-shared-data-source-connection-string?forum=sqlreportingservices
3. You may do a similar thing in code in C# or VB.net to get the values but again I believe the report must be hosted.  It's code is similar to here:

   [How to get the data source information from a SSRS report, using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589451/how-to-get-the-data-source-information-from-a-ssrs-report-using-net)
4. You can do a variation of 2 and 3 and consume the '.rds' file as xml and parse it out in C# or VB.NET.

All of these solutions require either the report being deployed or a FIXED location you know of on a server were the datasource for the report is at, except for 2 which I have never tried.  As far as I have seen the connection string is an embedded object not meant to be exposed as it could contain passwords.

Comment: Indeed I need jsut the Server and Database name. =) Not the whole connection string.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround could be to make the data source use an "Expression-based Connection Strings". And then use parameters to create this connection string, these parameters can then be used elsewhere in the report. For example:

```
="data source=" & Parameters!ServerName.Value & ";initial catalog=AdventureWorks"
```