# How to programmatically change password in a Shared Data Source?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, datasource

I am using SQL Server and SSRS 2017.

This is the code I used to change the pwd in the Data Source of my report in /MyFolder/MyReport:

```
string ReportPaths2 = "/MyFolder/MyReport";
DataSource[] dataSources2 = rsClient.GetItemDataSources(ReportPaths2);
for (int y = 0; y<dataSources2.Length; y++)
{
    DataSource ds2 = dataSources2[y];
    DataSourceDefinition dsd2 = (DataSourceDefinition)ds2.Item;
    dsd2.Password = "myPwd";
    rsClient.SetItemDataSources(ReportPaths2, dataSources2);
}
```

I have a Shared Data Source in /MyFolder/MyDataSource

When I tried the above code setting string ReportPaths2 = "/MyFolder/MyDataSource", I am getting the error:

> The operation you are attempting on item '/MyFolder/MyDataSource' is not allowed for this item type.

How do I change the pwd in the /MyFolder/MyDataSource ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you changing it via code?

Comment: There are a couple of code samples here to try. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589451/how-to-get-the-data-source-information-from-a-ssrs-report-using-net